# Перевод строки «did not earn this badge»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

На странице знака с указанным `userid` может быть строка «не **заработали** этот знак», хотя правильный перевод, видимо, такой: «не **заработал** этот знак»

[Вот, например:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/87/curious?userid=200000)

[image: страница знака со строкой «не заработали этот знак»]

[Пример такой страницы на enSO:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/87/curious?userid=222222)

[image: страница знака со строкой «did not earn this badge»]

Конечно, эти страницы далеко не самые посещаемые, и ошибка далеко не самая критичная, и я вообще не уверен, что ошибка имеет место, но почему бы и не исправить.

Comment: На самом деле проблема несколько шире, т.к. для `earn` сейчас используются разные переводы: `заработать`, `заслужить`, `получить`. Надо бы привести к общему знаменателю. А вообще, как Вы попали на упомянутые страницы - просто путем смены `id` в строке ввода адреса браузера?

Comment: Попал кликнув на новый знак в профиле (профиль -> активность -> знаки -> новые). В профиле было написано, что я недавно заработал знак, но видимо не все кеши обновились, и на странице по ссылке из профиля ещё пара минут висела надпись «не заработали этот знак». Страницы из вопроса получил заменой `userid`, да.

Comment: Вы всё правильно понимаете про кеши. Я уже писал на другой мете про эту проблему, симптомы точь-в-точь: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил пока на форму единственного числа:

> не заработал этот знак

Будет на сайте после обновления транзифекс и последующей пересборки движка.